# How can I compile multiple c++ files in a specific order in sublime text?

Tags: c++, file, build, header, sublimetext

I've created a .cpp and .h files for a class that will be used in the main file.  I have the folder with the files in the Sublime text editor.  However it seems to me that Sublime text runs the main file and imports the .h file only even though the .h file is also included in the .cpp file.  I came to this conclusion as i had the class constructor declared in the .h file and then defined in the .cpp file and it didn't work.  So I defined the constructor and the rest of the member functions in the .h file and it worked fine.

How can I allow sublime text to execute the build in the correct sequence so that I can have a .h file for the class and a .cpp file as well.

Comment: Header files do not get compiled.  And build order of your cpp files does not matter.  If you have multiple `.cpp` files they are all compiled separately and then you must _link_ them when producing the final binary.  If you don't provide the linker with this information, it will "not work"... whatever that means.  Please, any time something "doesn't work" you must state exactly what about it doesn't work -- and if you're getting an error, then show the entire error message.

Comment: Pass the path of `.h`'s folder to g++. Like this, `g++ -I<path_to_folder> main.cpp`. It includes all `.h` files in that directory.